# Firebase - Indexing on a wildcard

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am listening to Firebase using the following code:

```
this.objects
  .child(grouping)
  .orderByChild('delete-' + user)
  .equalTo(null)
  .on('value', handler);
```

My issue is that the following warning shows up:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding
>   ".indexOn": "delete-00569167-998b-4d4c-bc76-f710ae4c6dd8" at
>   /ef5e31f7-4227-45a1-87a0-d4a26a03c8e5/objects/data/00569167-998b-4d4c-bc76-f710ae4c6dd8
>   to your security rules for better performance

What I want to do is to index on all `delete-<guid>` *or at least `delete-<userId>` for the current logged in user.*
I wonder if it is possible to do a `.indexOn` on a `delete-*` in the security rules or if there is some other workaround for this to work.

Comment: Indexing on a guid is not very useful as it is by its nature random. What is the final goal here?

Comment: Cross-posted on firebase-talk: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/eRb52bhJP8M